# Send Local Notification when Timer reaches zero SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, timer, push-notification

Learning SwiftUI. I have an app that counts down timers from 30 min. As the timer doesn't work when the app is in the background, I have used user notification to get the current time app goes into the background and the time it comes to the foreground and subtracts the difference between those two times from the countdown timer I have going on so it reflects the time that has passed. Everything works fine. However, I need to be able to send a notification when the timer reaches zero.

As the timer is suspended every time the app goes into the background and the difference between how much time has passed is only calculated when the app comes into the foreground, I'm not able to find a way to send a notification when the timer reaches zero ( as the difference is only calculated when the app is in the foreground ) which negates the whole point of sending notification to let the user know the timer has ended.

Is there a way to figure out how to send a notification when the timer has reached zero without the app coming into the foreground? or any way to keep the timer running in the background so I can check if the timer has reached zero to send a notification?

Snippet of the code:

```
HStack {

// some code

}
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
   for: UIScene.didEnterBackgroundNotification)) { _ in
    if isTimerStarted {
         movingToBackground()
       }
                            
   }

                    
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
        for: UIScene.didActivateNotification)) { _ in
         if isTimerStarted {
              movingToForeground()
           }
                                
   }
```

// the functions created:

```
func movingToBackground() {
        print("Moving to the background")
        notificationDate = Date()
        
        fbManager.pause()
        
    }
    

    func movingToForeground() {
        print("Moving to the foreground")
        let deltaTime: Int = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(notificationDate))
        
        let deltaTimefill : Double = Double(deltaTime) / Double(300)
        
        fbManager.breakElapsed -= deltaTime
        
        if fbManager.breakElapsed <= 0 {
            notify.sendNotification(
                date: Date(),
                type: "time",
                timeInterval: 5,
                title: "AppName+",
                body: "Your timer has ended")
        }
        
       
        fbManager.breakFill += deltaTimefill
        
        fbManager.startBreak()
    }
```

Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: did you find any solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can queue up the notification at any time, with the date parameter set to when you want it to be displayed.